# mvc matcher and mvc mapping handler do not work the same

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

Doesn't spring handler mapping use spring HandlerMappingIntrospector to match received urls? So why doesn't mvc macther, which itself uses this class, work like handler mapping? For example, in @RequestMapping, you can not put / before the address and the program will work correctly. But in mvc matcher, if we do not put / before the address, that page will not be secured. Why?

```
@RequestMapping("contact") // it works
```

but:

```
http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers("contact").authenticated() //if we do not put / at the first of the home it does not recohnize the address
```

Answer (score 1):

When building the RequestMappingInfo, "/" is automatically prepended to the path when parsing the path in the PathPatternsRequestCondition constructor if not specified "/" by the user. The source code is as follows:

```
public PathPatternsRequestCondition(PathPatternParser parser, String... patterns) {
    this(parse(parser, patterns));
}

private static SortedSet<PathPattern> parse(PathPatternParser parser, String... patterns) {
    if (patterns.length == 0 || (patterns.length == 1 && !StringUtils.hasText(patterns[0]))) {
        return EMPTY_PATH_PATTERN;
    }
    SortedSet<PathPattern> result = new TreeSet<>();
    for (String path : patterns) {
        if (StringUtils.hasText(path) && !path.startsWith("/")) {
            path = "/" + path;
        }
        result.add(parser.parse(path));
    }
    return result;
}
```

This will result in "/contact“ not matching "contact”

Comment: Thank you, but what is the role of HandlerMappingIntrospector? Because I saw somewhere that mvcMatcher uses this class to match the and path extract variables.

Comment: The role of HandlerMappingIntrospector is to ensure that the backend has a corresponding request handler. If it does not exist, the DefaultMatcher is used to match the current request.